# Another device is connected to my Clash of Clans village

Tags: iphone, clash-of-clans

I have a problem when I am playing Clash of Clans, a message appears saying connection lost their is another device is connected to another village. I've changed the password of Game Center and Apple ID and iCloud. All of that didn't work. Note that I have all the information of the accounts.
I tried to contact Apple and Supercell and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

In case you know the other device, [this article](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421682-Can-I-transfer-my-village-to-a-new-device-) can help you out..


Source: [Supercell Game Support](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us)

Comment: Hello, please avoid using links that answer. Make a quotation or a step by step here. When a link is down, the answer has no value.